# Hiding DIV in TPL file based on if an image exists?

Tags: image, html, smarty, exists

```
<div><div style="margin-left:67px"><table style="border:1px #80A0BB solid;" padding="5px"><tr><td><a href="{$link.URL|trim}" target="_blank"><img src="{$smarty.const.DOC_ROOT}/images/thumbs/{$link.ID}-300x225.png" alt="" /></a></td></tr></table></div></div>
```

I'm trying to hide a div based on if an image exists on my server. How would I check to see if an image exists and hide the div if it doesn't exist? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to use write a function in PHP and then use it in Smarty.

In PHP:

```
function linkImageExists($link){

    //Check to see if image for link exists and return true if it does.
    // otherwise:
    return false;
}
```

In Smarty template:

```
{if linkImageExists($link)}
<div>
    <div style="margin-left:67px">
        <table style="border:1px #80A0BB solid;" padding="5px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="{$link.URL|trim}" target="_blank">
                        <img src="{$smarty.const.DOC_ROOT}/images/thumbs/{$link.ID}-300x225.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

{else}
    {* image doesn't exist *}
{/if}
```

You may want to consider turning `$link` into an object and then you can call functions on it, rather than having to use global functions which may producer cleaner code in the future.